# Parse Cloud Code: Push Notifications w/ Multiple Users on One Installation

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, parse-platform

I'm a nascent coder creating a simple iOS app. I'm experimenting with coding push notifications for the first time and I have a simple question regarding the Parse Installation Object and a scenario where multiple users log on the same device (let's say a loner iPad at a library).

Based on the Parse documentation I've seen, when a user subscribes to a channel - let's say "The Giants" - it saves this info on the Installation Object. But if the user logs out and another user logs in, does Parse assume that we are to erase the previous channels? Should channels therefore be saved to the User class first, and only saved to Installation when a user logs in? And similarly how do we handle advanced targeting where I want to query Installation for a specific User objectId? Is the best practice to always leave the last user logged in listed as 'owner'/'user'?

If you find the library example impractical, also consider something like signing into your Spotify account on a friend's device in order to play a private playlist at a party. I know these are less common scenarios, but I want to make sure I know how to handle them.

I'm new to Push Notifications so I may be missing something fundamental here, but if any experienced developer can lend some advice as to how they handle this scenario, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Store a reference to PFUsers when you save the installation. Add a field @"owner" and tag the pfuser to it.

After a user logs in, if they are not associated with the current installation, send an alert asking if they'd like to receive pushes on this device.  If that's the case, resave and update the current installation.  Otherwise leave it as is.

This is a tricky area, let me know what you come up with.

It's pretty rare that people will sign onto a service using someone else's phone, so I don't think its a huge issue if you want to just "see what happens" and if there's demand work it out.

Comment: Hi @Logan: can you let me know how to know the `current installation`? I am encountering some issues dealing with it. Thanks

Comment: @Malloc - have you tried `[PFInstallation currentInstallation]`

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 iOS apps using a single Parse application which supports push notifications for all 3 apps. I have a flag set on the project for the Release configuration for NDEBUG. I use `#ifndef NDEBUG` to set the boolean on a value I set on the current installation. This way it makes it easy to identify which installation that I can use for testing push notifications. I also use the `appIdentifier` value to filter to the application I am testing.

I also set other values as needed but these values are a good start.

```
if (debug) {
    [currentInstallation setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"debug"];
}
else {
    [currentInstallation setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"debug"];
}
```